# Checkbox with if else condition and && logical operator

Tags: c#, android, if-statement, xamarin, checkbox

I don't know what is going on with my condition. I know the statement is true but there is bug and I really don't know why my codes are not working properly. When the checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 were checked, its not working. It's only working in single condition like

```
if (chk1.Checked == true)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Here is my code:

```
if (chk1.Checked == true)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if ((chk1.Checked == true) && (chk2.Checked == true))
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice & Extra Sauce", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if ((chk1.Checked == true) && (chk3.Checked == true))
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice & Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if ((chk2.Checked == true) && (chk3.Checked == true))
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Sauce & Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if ((chk1.Checked == true) && (chk2.Checked == true) && (chk3.Checked == true))
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice | Extra Sauce | Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: The order of the `If else if` is why you are having this trouble..Change the order of  `if else` or The best way to do this is to use `Switch case`

Comment: Your second, third and fifth if's would not execute because it would enter the first if instead of those. Consider reordering them, setting the one checking more conditions first.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? When using else if only the first block that meets the condition will get executed. So if the first is true then the second, third and fifth else if blocks will never be executed.

Comment: What will i do guys? I will do seperate condition like if(){} and then if(){}?

Comment: @JaysonEGarcia you could do separate the conditions (zakharuk_pasha's answer) or reorder your conditions (too_cool's answer). But I would take a different approach wich I believe is easier to mantain (my answer)

Comment: Having chk2 checked and chk1 and chk3 not checked is a possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order of the `ElseIF` statement because whenever the `chk1` is checked the first statement will get executed regardless user checked chk2 or chk3. also `CheckBox.Checked` is a `bool` Property so no need to compare it with true or false

```
if (chk1.Checked  && chk2.Checked && chk3.Checked)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice | Extra Sauce | Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if (chk1.Checked && chk2.Checked )
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice & Extra Sauce", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if (chk1.Checked  && chk3.Checked )
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice & Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if (chk2.Checked  && chk3.Checked)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Sauce & Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
else if (chk1.Checked)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :D! I mean it worked perfectly :). I didn't now that i need to put the condition with operator in the first condition :3. Thank you again :)

Comment: @JaysonEGarcia you should really look into zakharuk_pasha's answer as that is even more easier to understand when going back to this code.

Comment: I already try his code and its working. And I got idea too. Thank you again for helping me to solve my problem :).

Answer (score 2):

Your first condition is invalidating the first two `else if`.

When you check chk1, it'll always fall into the first condition.

You should do something like this:

```
if (chk1.Checked == true)
{
    if ((chk2.Checked == true)) //chk1 and chk2 are checked
    {
         Toast.MakeText(this, "full rice & Extra Sauce", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    else //only the chk1 is checked
    {
         Toast.MakeText(this, "Extra Rice", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you :). This method is also worked :). And i get idea too.

Answer (score 2):

You could reorder your conditions (check other answers), putting the more restrictive ones firsts, but I wold suggest a more cleaner and easy to mantain solution.

```
List<string> additions = new List<string>();
if (chk1.Checked) additions.Add("Full rice");
if (chk2.Checked) additions.Add("Extra Sauce");
if (chk3.Checked) additions.Add("Extra Rice");

if (additions.Count > 0)
{
    string text = String.Join(" & ", additions);
    Toast.MakeText(this, text, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: This answer does not do the same as the code OP posted.

Comment: Why not @Mike ?

Comment: what if i only check `chk2` ? or `chk3`?

Comment: if i only have `chk2` checked the OP's code will do nothing. Your will do something.

Comment: @Mike, indeed in that case it would behave different. Wonder if it is correct or not.

Comment: I would definitely go with this answer if all combinations are a posibility